# Playing Card Class in C#

Tags: c#

Hello I'm a first year student and for one of our assignements about C# we are asked to make a blackjack game which includes a Playing Card Class with a property "cardValue" which has an int value from 1 to 13 and a property "description" which has the name of the card "1, 2, ..., Jack, Queen, King". I'm trying to use the "cardValue" property to determine the "description".

This is the code I have written so far:

```
class Card
{
    public int Cardvalue{ get; private set; } = new Random().Next(1, 14);
    private string description;

    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set 
        {
            switch (Cardvalue)
            {
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                case 5:
                case 6:
                case 7:
                case 8:
                case 9:
                case 10:
                    description= Cardvalue.ToString();
                    break;
                case 11:
                    description= "Jack";
                    break;
                case 12:
                    description= "Queen";
                    break;
                case 13:
                    description= "King";
                    break;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

I already figured out it doesn't work because I can't use "cardValue" to determine "description". But I'm struggling with finding a solution which does work. I know it may possibly be a very basic question but I would really appreciate some help!

Comment: Personally I’d use a constructor, but if you’re dead set on constructing it with a property, why not just set the description in the setter for the cardvalue?

Comment: There's no need for `Description` to have a `set` accessor or a backing field. The `get` accessor can *`return`* the description based on the card's value.

Comment: Consider using [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum)

Comment: To flesh out @madreflection's comment. Leave your existing `CardValue` int property the way it is. Then create a `string Description` property whose _getter_ contains nearly the same switch statement you have (changing `description=` to `return`) (and that has no _setter_)

Comment: The problem is that not every cards value directly corresponds to exactly 1 description. For example the King, Queen, Jack and the number 10 card are all worth 10 points, and the Ace is sometimes worth 11 but other times it's only worth 1 point.

Comment: _"P.P.S Since I'm new to stackoverflow I don't know how to mark this as solved in some way"_ You can move the solved/solution part to a new Answer to your own Question

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something important the suit !

This is a potential solution:

```
public enum Suit
{
    Clubs,
    Diamonds,
    Spades,
    Hearts
}

public class Card
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public Suit Suit { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Leverage of the built-in Queue<> object in C#. That collection has almost all the functionality we need to implement a deck of cards.

```
public static class DeckCreator
{ 
    public static Queue<Card> CreateCards()
    {
        Queue<Card> cards = new Queue<Card>();
        for(int i = 2; i <= 14; i++)
        {
            foreach(Suit suit in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit)))
            {
                cards.Enqueue(new Card()
                {
                    Suit = suit,
                    Value = i,
                    DisplayName = GetShortName(i, suit)
                });
            }
        }
        return Shuffle(cards);
    }
}
```

Finally, we need to handle the GetShortName() method. We don't want to be displaying "Ace of Spades" every time that card appears, rather we want to show the short name "AS" (or "5C" for 5 of Clubs, or "KD" for King of Diamonds, and so on). So we need a method to assign this short name (change it to our needs ie: replace J with Jack) to each card, like so:

```
public static class DeckCreator
{ 
    public static Queue<Card> CreateCards() { ... }


private static string GetShortName(int value, Suit suit)
{
    string valueDisplay = "";
    if (value >= 2 && value <= 10)
    {
        valueDisplay = value.ToString();
    }
    else if (value == 11)
    {
        valueDisplay = "J";
    }
    else if (value == 12)
    {
        valueDisplay = "Q";
    }
    else if (value == 13)
    {
        valueDisplay = "K";
    }
    else if (value == 14)
    {
        valueDisplay = "A";
    }

    return valueDisplay + Enum.GetName(typeof(Suit), suit)[0];
}
```

}

Comment: Suits don't matter in blackjack

Comment: Plus the King, Queen and Jack are all worth 10 points, and the Ace is worth sometimes worth 11 and sometimes worth 1 point

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way, using the way @madreflection described and @Flydog57 clarified:

```
class Card
{
    public int Cardvalue{ get; private set; } = new Random().Next(1, 14);
    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            switch (Cardvalue)
            {
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                case 5:
                case 6:
                case 7:
                case 8:
                case 9:
                case 10:
                    return Cardvalue.ToString();
                case 11:
                    return "Jack";
                case 12:
                    return "Queen";
                case 13:
                    return "King";
                default:
                    return "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. I first also tried using a constructor like @Taekahn suggested but I couldn't figure out how I would have to do that as it didn't seem to want to work either. So any help is still welcomed.
I also know that jack, queen and king is worth 10 in blackjack but the assignement told us to use the values of 11, 12 and 13.